# PySide6 and QML error: qtquick2plugin.dll: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, windows, qml, pyside, qtquick2

I use python version 3.11.1 in a virtual env and used `pip install pyside6` to install pyside6

The full error I get is:

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
file:///E:/project_path/gui_pyside6/first_gui/virenv/src/main.qml:1:1: Cannot load library E:\project_path\gui_pyside6\first_gui\virenv\Lib\site-packages\PySide6\qml\QtQuick\qtquick2plugin.dll: The specified module could not be found.
```

I have checked and qtquick2plugin.dll is in that folder. I even added the path to my environment paths, but nothing seems to solve it. How can I solve this?

This is my main.py

```
import sys

from PySide6.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide6.QtQml import QQmlApplicationEngine

app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

engine = QQmlApplicationEngine()
engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
engine.load('main.qml')

sys.exit(app.exec())
```

This is my main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 500
    title: "HelloApp"

    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "Hello World"
        font.pixelSize: 24
    }

}
```

Platform: Windows 10

Comment: As I know, in Windows, the error "The specified module is not found" may also mean that this dll cannot find one of its dependencies. I would check the dll with [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/)